# RealAmplitudes ansatz

Tags: qiskit, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

Does someone know why RealAmplitudes ansatz is made like this ? I can't find any research paper on it.

Why does it use 4 Ry Gate for one qubit ?